# Cannot install react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

when I try to install leaflet in my existing app,  it says following error.

```
ERROR:
PS C:\Users\baral\OneDrive\Desktop\react-starter-kit-master> npm install react-leaflet
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree   
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-starter-kit@1.0.0     
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project      
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from react-leaflet@4.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet
npm ERR!   react-leaflet@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\baral\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-02T10_33_19_748Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\baral\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-02T10_33_19_748Z-debug-0.log
```

When I try to do just, npm install leaflet, it gives the following error,

```
ERROR:
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/views/Maps/index.jsx 2:0-71
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-leaflet' in 'C:\Users\baral\OneDrive\Desktop\react-starter-kit-master\src\views\Maps'
```

how can i resolve it?

tried installing react-leaflet but throws error

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your node and npm version supports the react leaflet version you want to download.

Comment: They Sure does. I tried the same in fresh create app it worked. but, in my  this existing src code, it didn't and throws the given errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project use React v17 but the dependency needs React v18.

Try to update React with `npm install react@latest`.

Or install `react-leaflet` v3 if you still need React v17 for other dependencies legacy purpose.

Comment: tried but same problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the `react-starter-kit` dependency. This dependency seems very old (7+ years). Did you install it yourself ? What does it do ?

I suggest to remove it if you don't need it: `npm uninstall react-starter-kit`. And then try to re install `react-leaflet`.